# Size 26 curvy girl. Flying across country with Delta. Will I fit into the seat?

Tags: air-travel, safety, health

I'm a size 26 woman. I'm planning to fly across country with Delta. Will I have trouble to fit into the seat? What can I do to make the flight most comfortable for me? The flight is fully booked and don't have extra seats to buy.

Comment: The comments here aren't too bad http://fatshionista.livejournal.com/7123349.html but it is from 2011.

Comment: While your Q will be closed, maybe this will reassure: don't cancel, don't fret; get to the airport extra early, try to get an exit or bulkhead seat, and at the window. [Seat Guru](https://www.seatguru.com/) can help, as can quietly explaining your concern to the check-in agent.  And boarding/settling in might be easier if you pay for priority/early boarding and don't carry on anything but your purse.

Comment: If that's a recent picture in your thumbnail, you should not have a problem. I don't think you will even need a seat belt extension.

Comment: Don't worry about it!  Be sure to get an aisle seat for your convenience.  The airlines are totally nice about helping out those of us with an extra pound, just let them know beforehand.

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6587/will-she-be-able-to-fit-in-the-philippine-airline-boeing-777-300er-seat-comforta?rq=1

Comment: Also somewhat related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42978/will-i-fit-in-a-first-class-airplane-seat/42980#42980

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3356/3221

Answer (score 10):

My mother was a size 26 and traveled internationally with a number of airlines including Delta.

The seat pitch was perfectly fine in an economy seat. She did however have to ask for a seat belt extension (all planes carry these, just ask a flight attendant)

A useful trick to know is that on many planes, some outer seat arms will also raise, there is a 'hidden' button which the cabin crew will show you.

She also avoided emergency exit seats, as they had the tray table in the arm, which would not comfortably come out or sit flat.

Comment: "The seat pitch was perfectly fine in an economy seat": this of course has rather more to do with height than girth, at least up to a point.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what the exchange rate from women's sizes to men's is, but at my heaviest, I was at around a 60" waist.  I ended up having to borrow the "demonstration seat belt" section, use it as an extension to the seatbelt, but did manage to fit in one standard seat.

Mind you it was not the most comfortable flight, but I was just glad to get to where I was going.  Although, I'm not sure if anyone outside of first class on an Emirates Airbus A380 truly has a comfortable flight anymore.  As stated above, talk to the crew, they will help you out.